# Photoshop JavaScript: options to open a PDF as smart object

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to open a PDF file as a smart object layer in Photoshop (CS5). Croped to the trimbox.

It works when using `openDialog()` and `open()`.

But in case the property `asSmartObject` is true the `PDFOpenOptions.cropPage = CropToType.TRIMBOX` will be ignored.

There have to be options to open as smart object, like the `PDFOpenOptions`.
But I can't find them, did you?

My page should be croped to the trimbox with a minimum height/width of 400 px. Open the PDF as rendered pic won't work, because `PDFOpenOptions.height` ist deprecated for CS5 (and newer).

I don't want to render with a higher resolution, the PDF could be a small business card or a huge poster. Opening a file should be fast. This is why I choosed "open as smart object".

```
var openPDF = File.openDialog (undefined, undefined, false);
var openPDFoptions = new PDFOpenOptions;
openPDFoptions.antiAlias = true;
openPDFoptions.bitsPerChannel = BitsPerChannelType.EIGHT;
openPDFoptions.cropPage = CropToType.TRIMBOX;
openPDFoptions.mode = OpenDocumentMode.RGB;
openPDFoptions.name = "unnamed";
openPDFoptions.page = 1;
openPDFoptions.resolution = 72;
openPDFoptions.suppressWarnings = true;
openPDFoptions.usePageNumber = true;
app.open (openPDF, openPDFoptions, false)
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for Fixing my gramma and typing mistakes, I'm not a native speaker. And also mark code within my desciption!

Also I have an update: I tried the _scriptinglistener plugin_.

It doesn't work!